# Run Multiple MySQL Server with One host address?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, centos, load-balancing

I want to run 2 separate MySQL Server for one PHP base web server, like as an load balancer way.

I have two CentOS machine and over that separately MySQL server only. so what kind of service should I use that both server are ruining concurrently, which mean the web server load would be both MySQL Servers.

Can be used Ha Proxy?  Please suggest me.

Comment: I think you can run two mysql server on two different ports look at this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-servers.html

Comment: No Man! I am not talking about that two MySQL server would be one server, I want just run two different MySQL server that would be two separate server and need to access both server by one host or ip address. like one load balancer and under that two server connected, but how it would be possible with mysql .

Answer (score 0):

Use Amazon Aurora, which is more or less several MySQL instances automagically loadbalanced, as you described.